Unable to scrap "<div class="tdb-block-inner td-fix-index">" using Beautiful Soup
I am trying to scrap a website using BeautiFul soup and fetch texts under  but unable to fetch contents present under this header
a = 'https://insights.blackcoffer.com/how-will-covid-19-affect-the-world-of-work-2/'
response = requests.get(a)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'html.parser')
article_content = soup.find('div', class_="tdb-block-inner td-fix-index")


There's no text in that div. The HTML looks like <div class="tdb-block-inner td-fix-index"><span class="tdb-mobile-menu-button"><i class="tdb-mobile-menu-icon td-icon-mobile"></i></span></div>

Note that there are many divs with those classes. Some of them have text, some have images, and some have icons. You're only getting the first one, which just contains an icon. And since it's for the mobile menu, it's hidden on desktops.

You can use CSS selector .td-post-content to get article content instead:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

a = "https://insights.blackcoffer.com/how-will-covid-19-affect-the-world-of-work-2/"
response = requests.get(a)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")


article_content = soup.select_one(".td-post-content")
print(article_content.text)

Prints:
As business close to help prevent transmission of COVID-19, financial concerns and job losses are one of the first human impacts of the virus;
Not knowing how this pandemic will play out also affects our economic, physical and mental well-being;Despite this fear, businesses and communities in many regions have shown a more altruistic response in the face of crisis – actions which could help countries preparing for COVID-19.

...

